# How can I generate the GraphQL SDL from the implementation with graphene-django?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django

I'm using `graphene-django` to implement a GraphQL API in a Django project. With `python manage.py graphql_schema` I can dump the Graphene schema (introspection) JSON to a file. Is it possible to do the same for the Graphene schema in  [schema definition language (SDL](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/) (the schema in human readable SDL) representation?

Answer (score 2):

The following works for regular graphene in python:

```
str(schema)
```

Although it does not print out the descriptions of fields.

For Django from the command-line:

```
./manage.py graphql_schema --schema tutorial.quickstart.schema --out schema.graphql
```

Where `tutorial.quickstart.schema` is the location of your schema module.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do that with python directly but there is this little tool: [prisma-labs/get-graphql-schema](https://github.com/prisma-labs/get-graphql-schema)
You can start your server with introspection enabled and simply use the CLI tool on your running endpoint independed of the implementation.